# Serving tensorflow model using Flask

Tags: tensorflow, flask

I have Tensorflow model of Neural Network Translation in .pb format.
I want to serve it using Flask, because I want to use it in mobile appliaction.
Any idea how to serve the Tensorflow model using Flask?
Thank you before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if tensor flow works in the same way any model created out of scikit learn works.  I'll put my answer in... Hoping that this helps you in some way.

We had a similar problem for my company.  We had created a random forests model that classified a set of inputs and wanted to create an endpoint that would accept the inputs and spit out the classified outputs.

Initially, we trained the random forests on a separate server and pickled the model.

We then did 3 attempts (out of which attempt 3 worked best)

Attempt1:

Initialized the model at the start of the flask application

Result:
We had a micro server on the aws cloud and initialized a flask app with 8 workers.  8. random forest. instances. model was trained on m4 large server.  Server instantly crashed.

Attempt2:

Initialized the model whenever the path was called, i.e., called the unpickled the model file at the time of calling path.  so if "/classify" is a path, the model gets unpickled everytime the path gets called and then flask forgot about it

Result: 
Better.  Server did not crash.  When there was only one or two users, it worked fine... But it was definitely not a scalable solution... especially given that flask is synchronous and gunicorn kind of messes with the whole server

Attempt3:
Created a separate microservice that only had one path.

Server was initialized with one worker.  This was deployed on a completely different server (using aws lambda).

Result:
Stable outputs.  With very large volumes, it will definitely slow down (at which point you can consider moving to either node.js or using more workers)

Hope this helps